# Export brush stroke animation from Photoshop to a PNG sequence? Is there a script to do this?

Tags: adobe, script

We can use tool recording in Photoshop Actions to record the animation of the brush stroke and play it back, right? Can we export the playback in the form of a PNG sequence?

Is there a script perhaps to do this?

For example, the action shown here:

Can this playback be exported to a png sequence via a script?